# convert a steam of data to a stream of "value has not changed for a while" events in RxJS

Tags: rxjs

\I have a stream of strings. I would like to map it into a new stream that fire only when the stream value has not changed for more than 5 seconds.

e.g
assume one "-" bar represents one second:

```
--1--2-1-3-3-3------5-4---4--7-------8

--------------X------------X------X---
```

What is the best way to accomplish this? what operators can i use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`distinctUntilChanged`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html), then [`debounce`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html).

`distinctUntilChange` will reduce runs of the same values to the first one. `debounce` emits values if there isn't another that is emitted within a given time period.

```
--1--2-1-3-3-3------5-4---4--7-------8

       ↓ (distinctUntilChanged)

--1--2-1-3----------5-4------7-------8

          ↓ (debounce(5s))

--------------3------------4------7---
```